# How to place copyright next to footer menu?

Tags: html

How do I place my copyright next to my footer menu (secondary-footer)?  I want it to look like...

© 2016 sitename | secondary-footer

here is the html I'm working with

```html
<p id="copyright">&copy; <?php echo date('Y');?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'new-menu', 'container_class' => 'secondary-footer' ) ); ?></p>
```

here is my entire footer.php

```html
<footer class="site-footer">
    <!-- footer-widgets -->
<div class="footer-widgets clearfix">
<?php if (is_active_sidebar('footer1')) : ?>
<div class="footer-widget-area">
<?php dynamic_sidebar('footer1'); ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (is_active_sidebar('footer2')) : ?>
<div class="footer-widget-area">
<?php dynamic_sidebar('footer2'); ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (is_active_sidebar('footer3')) : ?>
<div class="footer-widget-area">
<?php dynamic_sidebar('footer3'); ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (is_active_sidebar('footer4')) : ?>
<div class="footer-widget-area">
<?php dynamic_sidebar('footer4'); ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- /footer-widgets -->
         <nav class="site-nav">
                <?php 

             $args = array(
                'theme_location' => 'footer'
             );

              ?>

             <?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?>

            </nav>
<p id="copyright">&copy; <?php echo date('Y');?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'new-menu', 'container_class' => 'secondary-footer' ) ); ?></p>

</footer>

</div><!-- container -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by enclosing them in divs like in following line of your code

```
<p id="copyright">&copy; <?php echo date('Y');?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'new-menu', 'container_class' => 'secondary-footer' ) ); ?></p>
```

Enclose above code in divs like this

```
<div style="float:left;width:50%;"><p id="copyright">&copy; <?php echo date('Y');?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | </div>
<div style="float:left;width:50%;"><?wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'new-menu', 'container_class' => 'secondary-footer' ) ); ?></p></div>
```

**Note**: You have to adjust your `Paragraph tag (with id="copyright")` between these divs.

**UPDATE**

You can make text closer with the help of `padding` property of css like this
If you wanna move text of `div` to the right side then use `padding-left:5%;`. For example:

```
<div style="float:left;width:50%;padding-left:5%;">
```

And If you wanna move text of div to the left side then use `padding-right:5%;`. For example:

```
<div style="float:left;width:50%;padding-right:5%;">
```

Padding property is use to move contents/text of div (not div itself) to any direction (left, right, top, bottom).

**Note**: You need to specify Padding's value (for demo I gave 5%)  as per your need. So change the value. And also don't forget to make classes of these divs, Because it would be better if you use these css properties in classes instead of `Style` inside div.

As an alternate you can reduce the width of div also to make them closer.

Comment: They appear on the same line now.  However, there is a large space between them.  How would I move them closer together, and center them?

Comment: @user6738171 Sorry for late reply! Answer has been updated.